# Browser Specific issue - One input file field data not assign to another input file field

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, cross-browser

```js
function assignFile(obj){
     var file2 = document.querySelector('#fileData');
     file2.files = obj.files;
     console.log(file2.files);
}
```

```html
   
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileData[]" id="fileData" multiple="" style="display: none;" />
    File: <input type="file" id="file" name="file" onchange="assignFile(this)" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I have two file fields. I want to assign `file` data to `fileData` field.
I have posted my code. This code working fine in chrome. But not working in mozilla. Could you please check.

Comment: You might be getting the console log in Chrome, from assigning a property, but in reality this doesn't work in any browser. For security reasons the `files` property is read-only, and you can't set it, only the user can.

Comment: @adeneo Any solution for this?

Comment: No, not really, it's a security thing, so you can't circumvent it.

Comment: In Chrome this code is working ...!!

Comment: @ChamalPradeep Yes chrome browser this code is working. Not working in mozilla for security reason